# Getting an information about a certain place?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, ontology, dbpedia

I want to know the hospitals or school located at a place. As for an example "**I want to find the hospitals in whole New york City"** or **"All schools in New Delhi"**. Is it a way to narrow down our search for a peculiar place(Going down to street level) for getting the attributes. I am trying to use sparql dbpedia endpoint for doing so.

Comment: select * where{
?x a dbpedia-owl:Hospital
}

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do that using latitude and longitude information. For example, you can use the following query to get that information.

```
select * where { 
  ?s a dbpedia-owl:School; 
   dbpprop:city dbpedia:New_Delhi;
   geo:lat ?lat;
   geo:long ?long.  
}
```

You can also use a query to get a schools in a given radius to the point you want.

```
select * where { 
  ?s a dbpedia-owl:School; 
   dbpprop:city dbpedia:New_Delhi;
   geo:lat ?lat;
   geo:long ?long.  
}
FILTER ( ?long > YOUR_LONG - radius && ?long < YOUR_LONG + radius &&
lat > YOUR_LAT - radius && ?lat < YOUR_LAT + radius)
```

Similarly you can use street level information too if those are present. For example, the following query provides the street information about the schools in New Delhi.

```
select * where { 
  ?s a dbpedia-owl:School; 
   dbpprop:city dbpedia:New_Delhi;
   dbpprop:street ?street .
}
```

The best thing I suggest is to go [one school resource](http://dbpedia.org/page/Modern_School_(New_Delhi)) and explore the properties it has. Then you can imagine what kind of queries you can generate.

Answer (score 0):

**select * where {
?x a dbpedia-owl:School.
?x dbpprop:location dbpedia:New_Delhi
}**

**1.** Is there any way to narrower the search using latitude and longitude of a place or using some street level address specifications.

Comment: Can the query result be enhanced using some other dbpedia entities as " **" dbpedia-owl:isPartOf " ** or any other dbpedia properties.